# Extracting each year from an item in a list in the format [yyyy,yyyy]

Tags: python, list

I am trying to append each individual year from an item in the list in the format[yyyy,yyyy] to an empty list. I am trying to append the first year and second year as well as all the years between them. This is what I have so far, but it is not adding the correct years to the empty list.

```
year_list=[yyyy,yyyy]
while True:
    year_int2 = int(year_list[1]
    i=0
    if i > difference:
         break
    value=year_int2 - i
    empty_list.appened(value)
```

Comment: [yyyy,yyyy] just symbolizes two years, for example, [1920,1940]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way.

```
startYear = 1986
endYear = 2014

empty_list = range(startYear, endYear+1)
```

Comment: I tried doing it this way and the list looks like [range(startYear, endYear)] instead of displaying each year in that range. Am I doing something wrong? The code I used looks like this:  list_year_values=range(year1_int,year2_int)
                year_list.append(list_year_values)

Comment: What is `year_list.append(list_year_values)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible way:

```
year_list = [1990, 2014]

y1 = year_list[0]
y2 = year_list[1]
a = y1
new_list = []

while a <= y2:
    new_list.append(a)
    a += 1

print new_list
raw_input()
```